# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

```
loginService.islogged()
```

Above function return a string like "failed".
However, when I try to run then function on it, it will return error of

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

and the cursor is indicate right after `connected` and before `.then`.

Below is the full function:

```
var connected=loginService.islogged();
alert(connected);
connected.then(function(msg){
    alert("connected value is "+connected);
    alert("msg.data value is "+msg.data);
    if(!msg.data.account_session || loginService.islogged()=="failed")       
        $location.path('/login');
});
```

UPDATE

Here is the `islogged()` function

```
islogged:function(){
    var cUid=sessionService.get('uid');
    alert("in loginServce, cuid is "+cUid);
    var $checkSessionServer=$http.post('data/check_session.php?cUid='+cUid);
    $checkSessionServer.then(function(){
        alert("session check returned!");
        console.log("checkSessionServer is "+$checkSessionServer);
        return $checkSessionServer;
    });
}
```

I am certain that the `$checkSessionServer` will result in a "failed" string. Nothing more.

Comment: You don't have a `promise` here.

Comment: what what needs to be called to get a `msg` - that should return a promise.

Comment: If the error is regarding `undefined`, then `islogged()` doesn't actually `return` a value. The definition of `islogged()` would likely be the source of your issues.

Comment: It is probably that your islogged method not returning a value in some case. After that I see that you are NOT using islogged as async method so it probably not returning promise at all.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski I just posted the islogged function. Hope that bring more insight.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You need to return your promise to the calling function.

```
islogged:function(){
    var cUid=sessionService.get('uid');
    alert("in loginServce, cuid is "+cUid);
    var $checkSessionServer=$http.post('data/check_session.php?cUid='+cUid);
    $checkSessionServer.then(function(){
        alert("session check returned!");
        console.log("checkSessionServer is "+$checkSessionServer);
    });
    return $checkSessionServer; // <-- return your promise to the calling function
}
```

Comment: This was actually the reason why my factory was not returning the promise. I forgot to do `return $http.post`. As soon as I added the prefix `return` to `$http`, it started working correctly.

Comment: @Devner thank you, I had forgotten to pass `return` as well.

Answer (score 4):

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined when calling a Django service using AngularJS.

If you are calling a Python service, the code will look like below:

```
this.updateTalentSupplier=function(supplierObj){
  var promise = $http({
    method: 'POST',
      url: bbConfig.BWS+'updateTalentSupplier/',
      data:supplierObj,
      withCredentials: false,
      contentType:'application/json',
      dataType:'json'
    });
    return promise; //Promise is returned 
}
```

We are using MongoDB as the database(I know it doesn't matter. But if someone is searching with MongoDB + Python (Django) + AngularJS the result should come.

Answer (score -1):

Return the promise value inside the function

```
return new Promise((done, err) => {
        ......
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi we were getting the same error in the test env
we are using the typescript , testing-library/react

I was using node v 14.X but other person was using node 16.X and above
they were getting this error.
So I updated my node version then able to replicate it on my local.

Then In test file, added the mockcall in the act, as it is affecting in updating the state  also

```
act(() => {
    mockAxios.post.mockImplementation(
        async () => Promise.resolve(availabilitySuccessMockData)
    );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to return promise in the function.
it suppose to be like:

```
   return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

    const { data:users } = await axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/" + Number);
    
    const { data: posts } = await axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?id=1" + Number);

    const completeData = [users, posts];

    resolve(completeData);
  });
```