# AngularJS pass parameter from Controller to Service

Tags: angularjs

I don't know how to pass data from the controller to the service as method arguments... I need to set in the controller the headers variable which is later added to the service which adds this later on to the http call

**controller**

```
angular.module('userControllers', []).
    controller('userController', ['$scope', '$q', 'Users', '$location',
        function($scope, $q, Users, $location) {

            $scope.viewUser = function(userId) {
                $location.path('/users/'+userId);
            };

            $scope.createUser = function () {
                $location.path('/users/create');
            };

            headers = {service:'json',resource:'users'};
            $scope.users = Users.query(headers);
            $scope.users.$promise.then(function(result){
                $scope.users = result;
            });

        }]);
```

**service**

```
angular.module('userServices', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Users', ['$resource', '$q', function($resource, $q){
        var factory = {
            query: function (headerParams) {
                var data = $resource('http://localhost:8080/gateway', {}, {
                    query: {
                        method: 'GET',
                        isArray: true,
                        headers: headerParams
                    }
                });
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.resolve(data);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
        return factory;
    }]);
```

In this setup I'm getting Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: UserProvider <- User ... not really sure how to fix this one out ...

Later edit : code cleanup... posted full code and new error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at new <anonymous> (http://localhost/frontend-pdi-angular-js/js/controllers/users.js:16:38)
at invoke (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.js:3918:17)
at Object.instantiate (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.js:3929:23)
at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.js:7216:28
at link (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-route.js:913:26)
at nodeLinkFn (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.js:6648:13)
at compositeLinkFn (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.js:6039:13)
at publicLinkFn (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.js:5934:30)
at boundTranscludeFn (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.js:6059:21)
at controllersBoundTransclude (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.js:6669:18) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Later edit #2 : some working code, but using no ngResource whatsoever

```
angular.module('userControllers', ['userServices']).
    controller('userController',
        ['$scope', '$q', 'Users', '$location', '$http',
            function($scope, $q, Users, $location, $http) {
                headerParams = {service:'json',resource:'users'};
                $scope.users = $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/gateway', headers: headerParams, isArray:true}).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.users = data;
                        console.log(data);
                    }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log(status);
                    });
            }]);
```

Comment: What is User which you have defined in the controller definition? can you show that service code as well

Comment: oops... forgot to remove that from the controller ... i'll need to edit the question a bit because I'm getting another error TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined (when reaching the line with $scope.users.$promise.then(...)

Comment: checking if this is a possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788171/typeerror-cannot-read-property-then-of-undefined

Comment: Instead of $scope.users.$promise.then try to use $scope.users.then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned, you are using a non-existent reference to a provider ($promise) in your code.  By simply setting the deferred to $scope.users and then acting on the 'then' of that deferred, you can solve this problem.

You can also simplify it a bit.  You are setting the deferred on the $scope object and then you're overwriting that with the resolved value of the deferred.  So you can do this instead:

```
Users.query(headers).then(function(result){
       $scope.users = result;
});
```

if you want to assign the deferred to a separate variable:

```
var deferred = Users.query(headers);
deferred.then(function(result){
       $scope.users = result;
});
```

Comment: $scope.users is undefined... data from my backend is coming out and worked before I needed to change the code to accept extra arguments

Comment: the view isn't populated ... not sure why... before trying these changes I saw data in the view ... if I make the request via $http .... it works ... but at least using your code I got rid of the initial error but ... another issue appeared ... maybe it's the topic of a separate question ...

Comment: Yeah, maybe ask another question and create a fiddle that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

replace controller with this code:

```
angular.module('userControllers', []). controller('userController', ['$scope', '$q', 'Users', '$location', function($scope, $q, Users, $location) {

        $scope.viewUser = function(userId) {
            $location.path('/users/'+userId);
        };

        $scope.createUser = function () {
            $location.path('/users/create');
        };

        headers = {service:'json',resource:'users'};
        Users.query(headers).$promise.then(function(result){
            $scope.users = result;
        });

    }]);
```

and factory with this code :

```
angular.module('userServices', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Users', ['$resource', '$q', function($resource, $q){
        var factory = {
            query: function (headerParams) {

                      return $resource('http://localhost:8080/gateway', {}, {
                    query: {
                        method: 'GET',
                        isArray: true,
                        headers: headerParams
                    }
                })


            }
        }
        return {
         query: factory.query
        }
    }]);
```

i think this will help you.

Comment: the call works now... but no data is sent to the view ... $scope.users is undefined

Comment: @ cristi _b use edited code. i think it will work now.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined ... i wrote a manual $http.get(...) call and data is coming ... but I need to figure out if something is wrong on the view side... so I'll also add the view code as well

Comment: nothing wrong on view side ... updating the question with some working code

Comment: @ cristi _b, could you please use my code once more.

Comment: had a syntax error near return { $resource } ... the undefined issue persists

Comment: @ cristi _b,i have solved the syntax error near return statement. when ever you get time please check

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('userControllers', ['userServices']).
controller('userController',
    ['$scope', '$q', 'Users', '$location',
        function($scope, $q, Users, $location) {
            headers = {service:'json',resource:'users'};
            Users.query(headers).then(function(result){
                $scope.users = result;
            });

        }])

angular.module('userServices', ['ngResource']).
factory('Users', ['$resource', '$q', function($resource, $q){
    var factory = {
        query: function (headerParams) {
            var data = $resource('http://localhost:8080/gateway', {}, {
                query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: true,
                    headers: headerParams
                }
            });
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(data);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
    return factory;
}]);
```

Try this. Your not include the `userServices` module into the `userControllers` module and you can omit `$scope.users = Users.query(headers);` part because if you put this this will call the query method.

Comment: same issue as described in other comments... I'm trying now to figure out why $scope.users is undefined ...