# Odoo error when calling Javascript function: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, promise, odoo, odoo-11

I'm developing an Odoo module in which I add a button to existing module, this button when clicked should execute a certain function.
Whenever I click this button, the function executes as desired but later I get an error:
**Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**

The button definition in the view:

```
<button onclick="myclick()">Click me</button>
```

The JS Code (after simplification):

```
function myclick()
{
console.log("hi");
}
```

What I tried:

- I simplified the code as much as I could but still the error appears.
- I researched the error and I got some results about **promises** but
  I still don't know how to resolve this error.

[image]

Comment: Try returning something in the function, `then` is expecting a promise to be returned. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788171/typeerror-cannot-read-property-then-of-undefined may give you a little more info.

Comment: You have to copy-paste the stack trace and the part of the code that this crashes on. Since this is Odoo enterprise we do not have access to it.

Comment: Maybe your click event is propagating to parent. Try stopping event propagation in onClick using e.stopPropagation() (note, e is an event - first arg of your myClick handler).

Comment: @ZbigniewZagórski .. Tried this but the error still exists.