# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" caused by shorthand arrow function form

Tags: javascript

I just noticed this weird thing. When I have this code, Atom JSCS linting does not give me any errors

```
findById: id => {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Zone.findById(id)
    .then(data => {
      resolve(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      reject(new Error('Sorry...'));
    });
  });
},
```

**but** my server returns the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

When I add `return` to this line, my app runs normal:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
```

It looks like my node server does not recognize the new syntax for functions. Is it because I need to use Babel? Or maybe I am completely on the wrong track...

P.S I referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788171/typeerror-cannot-read-property-then-of-undefined) Stack Overflow question to find out that I need to use `return` explicitly:

Comment: `It looks like my node server does not recognize the new syntax for functions.` which new syntax for functions? You always needed an `return` in a arrow function when you use a code block, this didn't change afaik.

Comment: That is what I am saying. I do not understand why Atom treats my block as single line. Because only in single line blocks you do not have to use `return` explicitly.

Comment: This has nothing do do with number of lines, what matters is whether you use a block `{}` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the brackets around your promise so the promise can return the resolved value.

```html
findById: id => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Zone.findById(id)
        .then(data => {
          resolve(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          reject(new Error('Sorry...'));
        });
    }
```

Also make sure that Zone.findById() always returns a Promise

Comment: Thanks! Yeah it worked. Exactly, it was because of curly braces...What do you mean by making sure it _always_ returns a Promise?

Comment: I'm just saying if Zone.findById is a custom API that you made somewhere else in your code instead of using an API from another technology (like MongoDB), make sure that it always returns a Promise

Answer (score 1):

Remove the brackets around the function body. The function returns `undefined` if you place brackets.

```
(() => { 1 })();
// undefined

(() => 1)();
// 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
findById: (id) => Zone.findById(id)
```

Why don't you use this construction? It is already a promise!